# How do I get the element that receives the keyboard input in web.whatsapp.com?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I want to provide handicapped users a way to operate web.whatsapp.com by keyboard only.

This works to some extent:

Users can jump around each tab and arrow keys.

Audio messages can be played / muted by pressing Space.

However, I have not found a way to open / large video or images:

[image]

Also, even I could find out which key opens / maximizes the images, I find it akward that my users would have to press 2 different keys

So the first thing I investigated was which element is currently active / selected.

My idea was to do the following (pseudo code)

```
if (UserPressedSomeSwitchToClickTheCurrentlySelectedElement)
    if (document.activeElement.type = 'wa-audio')
        SendSpace
    else if (document.activeElement.type = 'wa-Image') then
        'todo: investigate how to click this element
```

So the first thing I tried was to find out which element is the active one / the one which receives keyboard input.

To start off simple, I set the focus to the group search box and executed JS to tell me the element.

In this screenshot, one can see that the cursor is blinking in the group search box:

[image]

When I press the key "n" on my keyboard, it is printed in this element:

[image]

I have tried the following approaches to get the element which receives the input:

```
var e = document.activeElement;
if (e)
{
     alert('document.activeElement: ' + e + ', name: ' + e.name);
}
else
{
     alert('document.activeElement was nothing');
     e = document.querySelector(": focus");
     if (e)
     {
         alert('querySelector : focus: ' + e);
     }
     else
     {
         alert('querySelector : focus was nothing');
     }
}
```

The alert that I get is:

[image]

In some cases, e.className reveals a name.

When I am in the people selection tab on the left side however, e.className returns '', so I don't have any clue where I'm at.

Edit:

I would also like to be able to select / jump directly to the first user in the group list.

[image]

Comment: If this helps, input fields on whatsapp have an attribute name called `contenteditable` which should be set to `true`.

Comment: Can you show the actual code you use, since those lines look like you do it once only, which would of course fail to do what you want. You were asked in your previous version to show the code you are using, not some vague representation of it - perhaps you're doing it wrong™ but we'll never know - and what is `.Eval(JS)` and how does it relate to the code you've written. Also, how are you running code on someone elses website in the first place

Comment: @DonCarleone Can you please inspect an audio message in web.whatsapp.com? If I select it and then press Space, it will play. However, as far as I can see, it does not have "contenteditable". However, this is an element that I want to find using a function, so your suggestion does not help, I think. Can you please confirm?

Comment: @tmighty Couple of pointers, the question talks about finding the search input field, but then switches to talk about audio messages. I am completely at a loss here. Secondly, elements do not have to have a `name`. Thirdly, for finding out whether an audio message was selected, look at the styling of the elements (e.g. a `class` that is applied, or similar things). And lastly, there is a lot of mature accessibility software which might be a better idea to look at, as 'hacks' like these tend to break quickly and often.

Comment: And just to be sure, I checked that `document.activeElement` does work and returns the div that has the search focus on web.whatsapp.org and it does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript get selected element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72766026/javascript-get-selected-element)

Comment: @tmighty I understood that you were looking for input fields. Can you explain more clearly what exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DonCarleone I have edited my question to better reflect my original target.

Comment: @DavidMulder Ok, thanks, but how do I know the "final" element?

Comment: Currently web.whatsapp supports using tab to navigate the page. I'm guessing you're trying to make it easier than that..?

Comment: Btw @tmighty you can add the [accessibility] tag to the post. Maybe you;ll gain some visibility

Answer (score 2):

Hope I understood you right. With this code you can perform a click on a selected image in WhatsApp Web.

```
document.querySelector('.focusable-list-item[tabindex="0"] img').dispatchEvent(new Event('click', {bubbles: true}))
```

The item with the class `focusable-list-item` ist selected. This is mostly everything in your chat, that you can access by key up/down. To qualify the selector I use `[tabindex="0"]` which gives only the active (blue background) chat item. From there we go deeper until we meet the `<img>` tag. We perform a click, which bubbles up to the specific element, which triggers the fullscreen mode.

For me it works fine in Firefox console. I have no clue if it will work with your VBA.

**UPDATE**

So I tried using WhatsApp Web only by keyboard and it works very well for me. The ony thing missing is, that you can't maximize an image to fullscreen by keyboard. This is your problem, isn't it?

The most simple solution is to open the console (by [CTRL] + [SHIFT] + [I] in Firefox, Chrome, Edge), insert the following lines of code and hit enter.

```
document.addEventListener ("keyup", (evt) => {
    if (evt.which === 32) {
        console.log ('SPACE-BAR')
        document.querySelector('.focusable-list-item[tabindex="0"] img')?.dispatchEvent(new Event('click', {bubbles: true}))
    }
});
```

(You will get `undefined` as a result - this is the expected behaviour)

After that you can maximize a selected image to fullscreen by hitting [SPACE-BAR]. You can close them by pressing [ESC]. For videos and speech this works out of the box, like you already mentioned above.

Of course it is not useful for your users if they have to open the console first. You should write an chrome extension / firefox addon or more simple a tampermonkey / greasemonkey script for automatic execution.

**DISCLAIMER**

This will work until there is a major update in WhatsApp Web. Try contacting Meta and tell them that there is an accesibility issue with their plaform. This will help many more users worldwide I think.

Comment: Thank you, your code works great is really an image is selected. If not, it fails throwing an error. I am also looking for a way to find out if the selected message is an audio message or an image or a video message so that I can then perform the appropriate action.

Comment: To be more specific: Yes, your code work wonderfully great to achieve my final goal, but I still don't know how to know the currently selected element in order to perform the right JS on it. Do you see any way to find that out which element is currently selected?

Comment: Not that easy... Try ```document.querySelector('.focusable-list-item[tabindex="0"] [data-testid]')?.dataset.testid``` and you will get "audio-play" or "video-content". For other types (chat / image / contact / hyperlinks) you only get "tail-in" or "tail-out". Here you have to investigate further... Keep in mind, that Meta can change the code at any time so do proper error handling.

Comment: How do you know such tricks?????

Comment: How do you know that the name of this element is focusable-list-item?
With lots of Inspector'ing, I only found this name: 
<div class="_2wUmf V-zSs focusable-list-item" tabindex="-1"><div class="cvjcv EtBAv"><span dir="auto" class="i0jNr">SAMSTAG</span></div></div>

Comment: If the focus is in the people's tab, document.activeElement.className returns ''. Do you have any idea how to find how out where I'm at? I have added this question to my question.

Comment: I updated my answer and suggest you another approach. This relies on less elements and should have a bigger chance to survive a frontend update. I think your approch will get to complicated to maintain.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you suggest something else, please? I would like to create a script would directly select / the first person in the left side pane. I have added a screenshot to my post. I have used the Inspector to get it's name, but I didn't understand it. Could you tell me how to do this (with a bubble event like last time?) Seeing your code would help me learn it. Thank you!